# JavaScript modify winston-logger with a new log-level

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

I made an optimization for the logger module winston and don't know how to add a new loglevel

Maybe you're wondering what i need it for. I need this for an API with database queries.

An exampe of my logger is:

`logger.info('I am a Log');`

`20220202.163730-[m295] info: POST /v1/authenticate 401 45- 423.099 ms`

and want to log with a custom log-level named 'front'

for example:

`logger.front('I am a Log');`

`20220202.163730-[m295] front: POST /v1/authenticate 401 45- 423.099ms`

code from the module:

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const defaultFormat = format.combine(
  format.splat(),
  format.label({ label: '[m295]' }),
  format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYYMMDD.HHmmss' }),
  format.printf((info) => {
    if (info instanceof Error) {
      info.message = info.stack;
    }
    if (typeof info.message === 'object') {
      info.message = JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 2);
    }
    return `${info.timestamp} - ${info.label} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
  }),
);
const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.splat(),
    format.label({ label: '[m295]' }),
    format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYYMMDD.HHmmss' }),
    format.printf(
      (info) =>
        `${info.timestamp} - ${info.label} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
    ),
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: './logs/error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: './logs/server.log' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: './logs/front.log', level: 'front' }),
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: './logs/exceptions.log',
      timestamp: true,
      maxsize: 1000000,
    }),
  ],
});

logger.stream = {
  write: function (message, encoding) {
    logger.info(message.replace(/\n$/, ''));
  },
};

if (env !== 'development') {
  logger.add(
    new transports.Console({
      format: format.combine(
        format.colorize(),
        format.splat(),
        format.label({ label: 'm295' }),
        format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYYMMDD.HHmmss' }),
        format.printf(
          (info) =>
            `${[info.timestamp]} - ${info.level}: ${info.message} [${
              info.label
            }]`,
        ),
      ),
    }),
  );
}

module.exports = logger;
```

with the code:

```
const logger = require('../utils/logger');
logger.info('I am a log'); //or
logger.log('info','I am a log');
```

can i make a log

I want to make a log with the log-level front like that:

```
const logger = require('../utils/logger');
logger.front('I am a log'); //or
logger.log('front','I am a log');
```

Can somebody help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[custom-levels](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/examples/custom-levels.js)
Probably that's what you are looking for.

```js
const myCustomLevels = {
  levels: {
    foo: 0,
    bar: 1,
    baz: 2,
    foobar: 3
  },
  colors: {
    foo: 'blue',
    bar: 'green',
    baz: 'yellow',
    foobar: 'red'
  }
};

const customLevelLogger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'foobar',
  levels: myCustomLevels.levels,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ]
});
```